# Why are COVID-19 vaccine mandates considered a source of racism in the US?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, racism, vaccine

I've been reading a bit on the history of vaccine mandates, and it seems that multiple prominent groups have asserted that vaccine mandates are racist against minorities. I've read about the Tuskegee trials, and while there are similarities in them, I'm not seeing it. Note that they're asserting that the laws / mandates are racist, not anything about the vaccine itself.

Why do these US political groups think that laws (or mandates) made with respect to COVID-19 vaccination are racist?

Comment: Could you name the groups and/or add links to these statements?

Comment: Whatever similarities may exist, the Tuskegee trial is fundamentally different from a vaccine mandate.  Tuskegee claimed to be giving men free medical care while in fact withholding from those who were infected with syphilis, a fatal disease, treatment that was known to be safe and effective.  As a result, over 100 men died and several of their wives and children were also infected with syphilis.  I haven't heard any claims, not even the most unrealistic ones, that allege anything like this is going on with vaccines for COVID-19.

Comment: You should cite some of those claims and identify the groups who argue that. This is certainly not a commonly accepted view, so the reason one group might think that will likely depend on who we’re taking about

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. You mention that some groups have asserted that vaccine mandates are racist and then mention the Tuskegee trials without specifying how the two things are connected. I had a look at the Tuskegee trials and I saw it was a case where a medical treatment was denied, not mandated, how does it relate to a mandate?

Comment: @user141592 you could start with a few organizations such as black lives matter and Washington post.

Comment: @fluidcode that's what I'm asking.

Comment: You need to be way more specific.  Quote "multiple prominent groups" and their actual arguments, not just "I've heard it said".  Of course, Tuskegee is going to affect the trust people have in government provided health care.  But that is a different thing than stating that it leads to the conclusion that mandates are racist in themselves.  If "they" say "mandates are racist because of X and, by the way you know about Tuskegee which proves that racism?" you are asking about what X is in their argument.  Surely, before asking this question you have some quotes about that to share?

Comment: While new here, you have good seniority on other SE sites, asking you for a more clearly formulated question should not come as a surprise.